# Calculate time span over a number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have a table that has the following schema:

```
ID | FirstName | Surname | TransmissionID | CaptureDateTime
1  | Billy     | Goat    | ABCDEF         | 2018-09-20 13:45:01.098
2  | Jonny     | Cash    | ABCDEF         | 2018-09-20 13:45.01.108
3  | Sally     | Sue     | ABCDEF         | 2018-09-20 13:45:01.298
4  | Jermaine  | Cole    | PQRSTU         | 2018-09-20 13:45:01.398
5  | Mike      | Smith   | PQRSTU         | 2018-09-20 13:45:01.498
```

There are well over 70,000 records and they store logs of transmissions to a web-service. What I'd like to know is how would I go about writing a script that would select the distinct `TransmissionID` values and also show the timespan between the earliest `CaptureDateTime` record and the latest record? Essentially I'd like to see what the rate of records the web-service is reading & writing.

Is it even possible to do so in a single `SELECT` statement or should I just create a stored procedure or report in code? I don't know where to start aside from `SELECT DISTINCT TransmissionID` for this sort of query.

Here's what I have so far (I'm stuck on the time calculation)

```
SELECT DISTINCT [TransmissionID],
        COUNT(*) as 'Number of records'
  FROM [log_table]
  GROUP BY [TransmissionID]
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Not sure how to get the difference between the first and last record with the same `TransmissionID` I would like to get a result set like:

```
TransmissionID | TimeToCompletion | Number of records |
ABCDEF         |            2.001 |             5000  |
```

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT here, the GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: max(CaptureDateTime) - min(CaptureDateTime)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply `GROUP BY` and use `MIN` / `MAX` function to find min/max date in each group and subtract them:

```
SELECT
    TransmissionID,
    COUNT(*),
    DATEDIFF(second, MIN(CaptureDateTime), MAX(CaptureDateTime))
FROM yourdata
GROUP BY TransmissionID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Man that's such a simple way to do it, thanks for the answer, now I know how to approach this sort of thing going forward!

Answer (score 2):

Use min and max to calculate timespan

```
SELECT [TransmissionID],
        COUNT(*) as 'Number of records',datediff(s,min(CaptureDateTime),max(CaptureDateTime)) as timespan
  FROM [log_table]
  GROUP BY [TransmissionID]
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A method that returns the average time for *all* `transmissionids`, even those with only 1 record:

```
SELECT TransmissionID,
    COUNT(*),
    DATEDIFF(second, MIN(CaptureDateTime), MAX(CaptureDateTime)) * 1.0 / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0)
FROM yourdata
GROUP BY TransmissionID;
```

Note that you may not actually want the maximum of the capture date for a *given* transmissionId.  You might want the overall maximum in the table -- so you can consider the final period after the most recent record.

If so, this looks like:

```
SELECT TransmissionID,
    COUNT(*),
    DATEDIFF(second,
             MIN(CaptureDateTime),
             MAX(MAX(CaptureDateTime)) OVER ()
            ) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM yourdata
GROUP BY TransmissionID;
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions Gordon, I will look at how they could be applied in this application.